# Mysql distinct group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

happy pascal day.

```
('Afghanistan - Fixed'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile AWCC'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile Etisalat'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile MTN'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile Others'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile Roshan'),
('Afghanistan - Mobile WASEL'),
('Albania - Fixed'),
('Albania - Fixed ALBTEL'),
('Albania - Fixed AMC'),
('Albania - Fixed Tirana'),
('Albania - Interactive TV'),
('Albania - Mobile'),
('Albania - Mobile AMC'),
('Albania - Mobile Plus'),
('Albania - Mobile Vodafone'),
('Algeria - Fixed'),
('Algeria - Fixed CAT'),
('Algeria - Mobile Orascom'),
('Algeria - Mobile Others'), ...
```

I need to get Algeria, Albania and Afghanistan distinct, groupp by ?, you have idea ?

Comment: You really have two strings here. I would split them at the `-`.

Comment: happy fortran day to you

Comment: The data that you have provided is distinct, what do you want the desired result to be?

Comment: Just one Algeria, Albania Afghanistan ...

Comment: I have solution 
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `destination` , '-', 1 )) AS a FROM mytable

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you probably need something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, '-', 1)) countries
FROM table1
```

Output:

```
|   COUNTRIES |
---------------
| Afghanistan |
|     Albania |
|     Algeria |
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/099f8/5)**

That will also work

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, '-', 1)) countries
FROM table1
GROUP BY TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, '-', 1))
```

**[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/099f8/6)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ' - ', 1) from test;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba297/3